# Hiding of anchor tags before the page load

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, javascript-framework, jsp-tags

I have a list of permission URLs which are links to certain pages and this list comes from the database. 
Now, there are jsp pages all across the application and they have certain links which display. These jsps are older jsps and the code is all there. 
Right now, Based upon the list of permissions I retrieve from database, I would like to either show or hide these links.

Is there any centralized way of doing this either using a javascript snippet or jsp or combination which can be put in all jsps?

The authorization part to these urls is already taken care, the display of the URLs which are usually anchor tags should be taken care, other than the way of actually going into each and every jsp and checking in session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going through each page you could probably set up a combination of Java and JavaScript to accomplish this task.

I would personally use jQuery. Set a JavaScript variable based on permission level, then use jQuery to loop through all your anchor/link to parse off of link name or common attribute to remove or hide them.

```
var permissionLevel = <%=bean.getPermissionLevel()%>

switch(permissionLevel ){     
    case 0:
        $("a").each(function(){
            var link = $(this).attr("href");
            if(link == 'myLinkName'){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        })
}
```

In this example I used a numeric value as the permission level. You could easily use a string value and use if statements instead of a case state, but this shows the general idea.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out and will let you know

Comment: I added similar function in     $(document).ready( function() and it works fine in the regular jsps however this same function is put in the header jsp it doesnt work in firefox and in IE it complains about null object.Is there any alternative to document ready function? so I can generalize it and put it in header?

Comment: Could be that the <%=bean.getPermissionLevel()%> is null, try surrounding this in quotes so if the bean or permission level is null when the page loads, you just have an empty string in your javascript, otherwise it is malformed. You might also consider some logic, based on the assumption that the bean or value is null, to set a default value to the javascript permission level.

Comment: The jmesa library is missing from header jsps and then there was protype.js which was causing conflicts.. Thank you for the ideas..!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create my own tag definition that take in security roles and include or exclude links in the page if the role validation passes. If you do it in javascript and only hide the links you can still inspect the page and access the urls.. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can make all anchor tags without a "show" class hidden by default using a single CSS expression:

```
a:not(.show) {
    display: none;
}
```

and then at the point you wish to show them (I'd say in your case this would be the document ready function), simply add the CSS class "show" which will invalidate the rule above.

JavaScript:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].className = "show";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out as well and will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSP tag libs. Wrap the URL link in the taglib. For example spring security has something like this

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
   // display something
</security:authorize>
```

in the taglib, you will check if the user is logged in and he has certain permissions or roles and if he has you will either write it or skip it...

Answer (score 0):

If you send a javascript array of your permitted pages to the browser, you could then loop over all links to check and see if they are in the list. You probably have some links that are not secured so you would have to handle those somehow too.